# php parse_str convert plus(+) to spaces

Tags: php

I'm using `parse_str` to get an array from a string, which is like:

```
$str='a=123&b=456&Signature=aaaa/bbb+i8=&Satus=bbbb';
```

I noticed that the function `parse_str` does convert plus to space, but how can I avoid this things.

new edit:
The `$str` to a value that I get from a string which is like this:

```
YT0xMjMmYj00NTYmU2lnbmF0dXJlPWFhYWEvYmJiK2k4PSZTYXR1cz1iYmJi
```

I get the string and make base64_decode,then get the `$str`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because [`parse_str()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) expects a [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) string as its first argument or, more specifically, a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) which is of mime-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

For historical reasons a `+`-sign, besides its percent-encoded counterpart `%20`, is also interpreted as a space, in the context of this mime-type. [Wikipedia has this to say about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type):

> ### The application/x-www-form-urlencoded type
>
> ---
>
> [...] The encoding used by default is based on an early version of the
>   general URI percent-encoding rules, with a number of modifications
>   such as newline normalization and replacing spaces with + instead of
>   %20. [...]

So, you need to make sure you feed `parse_str()` a properly URL-encoded string to get the characters that you expect. If you expect a `+` it should first be properly percent-encoded as `%2B`, before you pass it to `parse_str()`.

Comment: So you  mean I shoud do like this `str_replace('+','%2B',$str)` before the `parse_str($str, $arrRes)`?

Comment: @code.g Yes, but `str_replace('+',' ',$str);` will actually do the trick as well. I just wanted to be thorough in my answer. And another thing: if the base64 encoded data was meant to represent actual query string compliant data, you might want to inform whomever you received this from about URL-encoding as well, if the `+`-sign was meant to be taken literal.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str='a=123&b=456&Signature=aaaa/bbb+i8=&Satus=bbbb';
$new_string = str_replace('+', '.', $str);
parse_str($new_string,$old_string);
$signature = str_replace('.', '+', $old_string['Signature']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because parse_str in meant to be used on query strings and whenever there is space in string, it is converted into + so parse_str converts the + to space.

you can pass ths string through str_replace to undo this

$old_string = "a=123&b=456&Signature=aaaa/bbb+i8=&Satus=bbbb";
$string = parse_str($old_string);
$new_string = str_replace('+', ' ', $string);

If you face any issues then lemme know

Answer (score 0):

You shoud elaborate you given code use for what. Is it for HTTP Request (like curl post method) or Request URL GET Method.

If its a url, then try use either you replace those char using str_replace method or use urlencode method.

Please refer to these manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
and
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Read this too:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php